# Divide output from simple html dom

Tags: html, dom, output

With simple_html_dom i get info from my HTML file, but thing is that everything is in 1 variabile($actor) and i need output each name in one variabile so for my HTML code it can looks like this:
$output1 = Owen Wilson
$output2 = Vince Vaughn
....
its importnat for me to get it like this because i dont want to just print it as a text, i want to work with it name by name. I can use strlen  for this specific case but if i change a HTML file it will not help anymore :)

HTML:

```
<span data-truncate="340">
                            <a href="/tvurce/151-owen-wilson/">Owen Wilson</a>, <a href="/tvurce/2012-vince-vaughn/">Vince Vaughn</a>, <a href="/tvurce/17667-rose-byrne/">Rose Byrne</a>, <a href="/tvurce/10578-will-ferrell/">Will Ferrell</a>, <a href="/tvurce/80278-dylan-o-brien/">Dylan O´Brien</a>, <a href="/tvurce/53638-joanna-garcia-swisher/">Joanna Garcia Swisher</a>, <a href="/tvurce/95173-tobit-raphael/">Tobit Raphael</a>, <a href="/tvurce/25244-max-minghella/">Max Minghella</a>, <a href="/tvurce/66023-josh-gad/">Josh Gad</a>, <a href="/tvurce/40697-jessica-szohr/">Jessica Szohr</a>, <a href="/tvurce/74011-tiya-sircar/">Tiya Sircar</a>, <a href="/tvurce/74706-anna-enger/">Anna Enger</a>, <a href="/tvurce/94774-josh-brener/">Josh Brener</a>, <a href="/tvurce/86955-troy-faruk/">Troy Faruk</a>, <a href="/tvurce/404-john-goodman/">John Goodman</a>
                        </span>
```

PHP code:

```
$ret = $html->find('span[data-truncate*="60"]');                        //rezia

foreach ($ret as $actor) {
    echo "Actors are: $actor<br/>";
      }
```

So guys any idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what are you trying to achieve but if you want to have variables with actor names why not to add them to array?

```
$ret = $html->find('span[data-truncate*="340"] a');

$actors = array();
foreach ($ret as $actor) {
    $actors[] = $actor->innertext;
}
```

You can access individual actors like `$actors[0]`…

Edit: It just looks you forgot `a` in your selector.